# PHP script with crontab loop

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script that have a long execution time.
I've set

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000);
```

and with the Browser the script goes well.

But when I call with crontab like

```
0 3 * * * wget -q -O - "http://mysite.it/script.php"
```

I can see that the script start and finish (I've a logger implemented) but the log tell me that the script is continously invoked as if crontab does not recognize the end of the script and it did start again every time.

Comment: better to use background process there

Comment: I would look for a simpler explanation than "the crontab does not recognize the end of the script" first.  Do you have any recursion in your script? an infinite loop? Could something other than the crontab also be invoking the script, such as an http request?

Comment: I have a loop but generallty it finish and write in the logfile the info like:    $log->LogInfo("Script end");

Comment: The script use curl for download a file and parse it to produce a csv. I have other scripts like this that almost equal, but download and create smaller files

Comment: In other words when you execute a con job it executes when is executed according to the time you set your time is once per day at 3AM. This cron executes what ever you ask for and there is not feedback process normally. You can use commands tools like `ps aux |grep wget`  to know if the process is running once it starts. Now wget tries to download a script and stops when is an utility for non-interactive download of [files from the Web.](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) In other words I agree your issue is not with cron probably. Why do you use the ` - ` option with the wget command?

Comment: I found this option for wget --timeout=0 --tries=1